# async methode how can i bind values to IEnumarable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, android-asynctask

Here i get some values from server

```
public class iAuth
    {
        public string resultStatus { get; set; }
        public string userName { get; set; }

    }
```

This IAuth i need to bind my data

```
private async Tas<bool> GetValiedSession(string _SesToken)
    {
        string Baseurl = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Baseurl"];
        var values = new Dictionary<string, string>{
                      { "productId",  WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["productId"] },
                      { "productKey",  WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["productKey"] },
                      { "userName", "gosoddin" },
                      { "securityToken",_SesToken  },
                      };
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var _json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(values);
            var content = new StringContent(_json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            var response = await client.PostAsync(Baseurl + "validate/session", content);              
            //var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
           IEnumerable<iAuth> aa  = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); ;
            //  return Ok(responseString);
            return true;
        }

    }
```

Here how can i bind values to `IEnumarable<iAuth>`
Here im getting Error as cant convert String to system.colllection.Generic

Comment: whats is `iAuth` in `IEnumerable<iAuth>`? and how your response look like?

Comment: @er-mfahhgk Iauth is my class File

Comment: show that class file. add this in your post

Comment: @er-mfahhgk i had jus updated my file FOr urs I had copied Here public class iAuth
    {
        public string resultStatus { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Im getting Response as   {
    "resultStatus": "success",
    "language": "en",
    "region": "us",
    "securityToken": "EADBF179-80BE-4E55-82EE-66444AF3A84E|13|1549445466175",
    "userName": "gosoddin",}

Comment: Answer added try it and let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to read the content of your response to `IEnumerable<>`

```
IEnumerable<iAuth> aa  = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

But `ReadAsStringAsync()` returns `string` so that's why the error comes.

So you need to deserialize your `Response.Content` to a specific type like,

```
string response  = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<iAuth>(response);
```

Now you can get `resultStatus`  and `userName` by using like,

```
string status = result.resultStatus;
string name = result.userName;
```